# Flutter, preview of app and design plugin?

Tags: flutter

Why flutter does not contain a preview of the app while we are programming it?

Is there any design plugin to be able to drag and drop widgets like in android studio for android apps?

It is difficult to build an interface from code without having a preview of the application.

Thanks!!

Comment: The world needs a flutter designer vscode extension!

Comment: i don't think it is very important, but a preview feature will be most appreciated ,just like with jetpack compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have emulator. What else do you want to **preview your app**?

[image: emulaor]

Also on dart dev tools, you have a render tree and widget inspector. There is an option called show debug paint that I highly use to see the size and boundaries of widgets, and many other options I didn't discover yet.

[image: dart devtools]

You can use [flutter studio](https://flutterstudio.app/) if you want to create your ui by dragging and dropping widgets but I didn't use it.

And I just found [that](https://norbert515.github.io/widget_maker/website/).

I really didn't understand what you mean by **previewing**.

Comment: I didn't know flutter studio, I think it's going to be useful for me.

Thanks!!

Comment: By "previewing" I guess the user meant to get a preview of the design of the app without having to compile/build it for your phone or the emmulator.

In Android Studio with Java SDK you have to design the app's user interface using XML. The XML editor used to have a preview mode where you could see how this XML would look like when you run the app on your phone.

Additionaly you could drag n drop items and change properties(size position etc) by using your mouse.

Comment: what if the application can't build and i need to know what the screen looks like , for example with jetpack compose for native android apps there is the possibility to preview a widget in isolation from the whole app and without compilation

Comment: i don't just want to preview my whole running app , the question is about previewing a particular screen/widget for example just like in jetpack compose using the annotation @preview

Comment: The reason a preview within Android Studio itself would be great is because the emulator is quite heavy and we wouldn't want to leave it running throughout

Comment: Previewing is pure layout/ui-design. No code, no interaction,... It would be nice, to determine the exact place of widgets within in a widget.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: This is not a first party tool.

I think what you're looking for is this:
https://flutterstudio.app/

It's a drag and drop editor for building Flutter layouts.

My personal recommendation is to use an emulator and learn how all the layout widgets work. Thanks to hot-reload it's super easy to experiment and create what you're looking for.